# Meteor HTTP.call undefined on Client-side, working on Server-side

Tags: javascript, http, meteor, get

I am currently trying to learn how to do HTTP requests in Meteor. When I run the code, I can properly see the data in the console. However, on the client side all I get is "undefined". I believe I'm running the HTTP.get method synchronously.

.JS file

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.test.helpers({

        testGET: function(){
            var origin = Meteor.call('fetchFromService');
            console.log(origin);  //-- Displays 'Undefined'
        }

    });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.methods({
        fetchFromService: function() {
            this.unblock();
            var url = "https://httpbin.org/get";
            var result;

            try{
                result = HTTP.get( url );
            } catch(e) {
                result = "false";
            }

            console.log(result.data.origin); //-- Displays the data properly
            return result.data.origin;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Read this:
[https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/understanding-sync-async-javascript-node/](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/understanding-sync-async-javascript-node/)

Then, this in the Meteor documentation:
[http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_call](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_call)

On the client, if you do not pass a callback and you are not inside a stub, call will return **undefined**, and you will have no way to get the return value of the method. That is because the client doesn't have fibers, so there is not actually any way it can block on the remote execution of a method

Answer (score 1):

It's async, you have to pass a callback to the `call` function:

```
var origin = Meteor.call('fetchFromService', function(err, data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

If you don't pass the callback, `origin` will be `undefined` until the request finishes.

Comment: Thank you. I also found an article that explains this a bit better for my understanding. [https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/understanding-sync-async-javascript-node/](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/understanding-sync-async-javascript-node/)